# IntelliJ cannot download sources from private ECR

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, amazon-ecr

I am receiving the following IntelliJ error -

```
Cannot download sources

sources not found for: <my-artifact>
```

This only happens when I try to download sources that are in my company's AWS ECR.

I am connected to the company's VPN, and I have a fresh AWS Code Artifact token.

I have tried running:

```
mvn dependency:sources
```

Any ideas to how I can get this to download internal sources?

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any errors in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")? Is your local repo checked according to recorded events in log?

Comment: @y.bedrov nope, I cleared the logs and tried again, nothing there

Comment: No maven related records about downloading?

Comment: @y.bedrov nothing..

Comment: Is your internal repository mentioned in "Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Repositories"?

Comment: @y.bedrov is, it is